# How can I don't keep changing Active Storage attachments URLs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Every time I retrieve an ActiveStorage attachment URL (using `object.attachment.service_url`), is a new one. Is there a way to use always the same one?

EDIT

`storage.yml` file

```
amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= ENV['AWS_KEY'] %>
  secret_access_key: <%= ENV['AWS_SECRET'] %>
  region: 'sa-east-1'
  bucket: 'production-bucket'

test:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= ENV['AWS_KEY'] %>
  secret_access_key: <%= ENV['AWS_SECRET'] %>
  region: 'sa-east-1'
  bucket: 'staging-bucket'

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this line can help you

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path(Object.attachement, only_path:true)
```

You can add this method to your model

```
def attachment_url
    if self.attachment.attached?
      Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path(self.attachement, only_path:true)
    else
      nil
    end
  end
```

And call it from anywhere.

If your model has many attachments

```
def attachment_url(item_attached)
    if item_attached.attached?
      Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path(item_attached, only_path:true)
    else
      nil
    end
  end

Object.attachement_url(Object.image)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. How does rails_blob_path/ulr works? Im using Amazon S3 but I can't find my images from the generated url. For example, I got something like `rails/activestorage/blobs/....` but I don't even have a rails or activestorage folder at my S3.

Comment: ActiveStorge doesn't work like other gems, like paperclip, it doesn't save the uploaded files like images, docs, etc. ActiveStorage converte the files in "blobs" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object). When you call the method rails_blob_path, you are really converting the blob to the original format and rails returns the URL for that blob converted. If you have configured your development environment in local you can search a folder with name .storage in your project's root and you can see how are your filed uploaded

Comment: Sorry if it is obvious, but what configurations are you talking about? I have configured with `config.active_storage.service`, using `:local` locally and `:amazon` for S3. Also, I have a `storage.yml` for amazon, test and local. I don't have this .storage file. This should be the one to define where my `rails_blob_path` files are stored? 
Thansk for helping me.

Comment: I edited the Question adding `storage.yml`. I'm able to hit the URL locally, at localhost, but I still couldn't hit at production/staging. I've tried using 2 differente ways from Amazon Docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteEndpoints.html), but was unreacheable.